# How to update DOM content inside WebBrowser Control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, dom, webbrowser-control

I've a windows .Net `Form` which contains a `WebBrowser` Control.
This `WebBrowser` displays a webpage based on its `Url` property. 
Can I modify the DOM of the displayed page inside the `WebBrowser` control ?
If yes, how to ?

Comment: It is possible. WebBrowser is supposed to have a property called Document which you can access the html through htmldocument on managed code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Comment: Here's the link to that specific property I mentioned http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx

Comment: Is it read only (as I see it only contains a getter) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those who are interested, here's the solution:

```
HtmlElement headElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptElement = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement domScriptElement = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElement.DomElement;
domScriptElement.text = "function applyChanges(){/*DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE*/}";
headElement.AppendChild(scriptElement);

// Call the nextline whenever you want to execute your code
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("applyChanges");
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx:

> You can also manipulate the contents of a Web page through the Document property, which contains an HtmlDocument object that provides managed access to the HTML document object model (DOM) for the current page. This property is useful, when used in combination with the ObjectForScripting property, to implement two-way communication between your application code and dynamic HTML (DHTML) code in a Web page, letting you combine Web-based controls and Windows Forms controls in a single user interface. You can use the Document property to call scripting code methods from your application. Your scripting code can access your application through the window.external object, which is a built-in DOM object provided for host access, and which maps to the object that you specify for the ObjectForScripting property.

Comment: At the end of the link, you'll find some examples.